# How to perform pairwise division based on row grouping

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame that is made the following way:

```
df <- structure(list(celltype = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Bcells",
"DendriticCells", "Macrophages", "Monocytes", "NKCells", "Neutrophils",
"StemCells", "StromalCells", "abTcells", "gdTCells"), class = "factor"),
    sample = c("SP ID control", "SP ID treated", "SP ID control",
    "SP ID treated", "SP ID control", "SP ID treated", "SP ID control",
    "SP ID treated", "SP ID control", "SP ID treated", "SP ID control",
    "SP ID treated", "SP ID control", "SP ID treated", "SP ID control",
    "SP ID treated", "SP ID control", "SP ID treated", "SP ID control",
    "SP ID treated"), `mean(score)` = c(0.160953535029424, 0.155743474395545,
    0.104788051104575, 0.125247035158472, -0.159665650045289,
    -0.134662049979712, 0.196249441751866, 0.212256889027029,
    0.0532668251890109, 0.0738264693971133, 0.151828478029596,
    0.159941552142933, -0.14128323638966, -0.120556640790534,
    0.196518649474078, 0.185264282171863, 0.0654641151966543,
    0.0837989059507186, 0.145111577618456, 0.145448549866796)), .Names = c("celltype",
"sample", "mean(score)"), row.names = c(7L, 8L, 17L, 18L, 27L,
28L, 37L, 38L, 47L, 48L, 57L, 58L, 67L, 68L, 77L, 78L, 87L, 88L,
97L, 98L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
> df
         celltype        sample mean(score)
7          Bcells SP ID control  0.16095354
8          Bcells SP ID treated  0.15574347
17 DendriticCells SP ID control  0.10478805
18 DendriticCells SP ID treated  0.12524704
27    Macrophages SP ID control -0.15966565
28    Macrophages SP ID treated -0.13466205
37      Monocytes SP ID control  0.19624944
38      Monocytes SP ID treated  0.21225689
47        NKCells SP ID control  0.05326683
48        NKCells SP ID treated  0.07382647
57    Neutrophils SP ID control  0.15182848
58    Neutrophils SP ID treated  0.15994155
67      StemCells SP ID control -0.14128324
68      StemCells SP ID treated -0.12055664
77   StromalCells SP ID control  0.19651865
78   StromalCells SP ID treated  0.18526428
87       abTcells SP ID control  0.06546412
88       abTcells SP ID treated  0.08379891
97       gdTCells SP ID control  0.14511158
98       gdTCells SP ID treated  0.14544855
```

What I want to do is to compute division  of score based on `treated` and `control` sample within `cell type` grouping.

The following Excel image illustrate the example. We're after the right most column. For example in Bcells (0.155/0.161 =  0.967).

[image]

At the end of the day I'd like to get the df that looks like this:

```
celltype            sample          Pairwise division
Bcells              SP ID treated   0.967630031
DendriticCells      SP ID treated   1.195241574
Macrophages         SP ID treated   0.843400255
Monocytes           SP ID treated   1.081566841
NKCells             SP ID treated   1.385974647
Neutrophils         SP ID treated   1.053435786
StemCells           SP ID treated   0.853297563
StromalCells        SP ID treated   0.942731303
abTcells            SP ID treated   1.280073915
gdTCells            SP ID treated   1.002322158
```

How can I achieve that in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you spread to wide form, it's pretty trivial:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% spread(sample, `mean(score)`) %>% 
    mutate(pairwise_division = `SP ID treated` / `SP ID control`)

##          celltype SP ID control SP ID treated pairwise_division
## 1          Bcells    0.16095354    0.15574347         0.9676300
## 2  DendriticCells    0.10478805    0.12524704         1.1952416
## 3     Macrophages   -0.15966565   -0.13466205         0.8434003
## 4       Monocytes    0.19624944    0.21225689         1.0815668
## 5         NKCells    0.05326683    0.07382647         1.3859746
## 6     Neutrophils    0.15182848    0.15994155         1.0534358
## 7       StemCells   -0.14128324   -0.12055664         0.8532976
## 8    StromalCells    0.19651865    0.18526428         0.9427313
## 9        abTcells    0.06546412    0.08379891         1.2800739
## 10       gdTCells    0.14511158    0.14544855         1.0023222
```

Note that you should probably fix your column names so you don't have to use backticks so often.

To get *precisely* the desired result, gather back to long, filter to just treated rows, and select the desired columns:

```
df %>% spread(sample, `mean(score)`) %>% 
    mutate(pairwise_division = `SP ID treated` / `SP ID control`) %>% 
    gather(sample, `mean(score)`, starts_with('SP')) %>% 
    filter(sample == 'SP ID treated') %>% 
    select(celltype, sample, pairwise_division)

##          celltype        sample pairwise_division
## 1          Bcells SP ID treated         0.9676300
## 2  DendriticCells SP ID treated         1.1952416
## 3     Macrophages SP ID treated         0.8434003
## 4       Monocytes SP ID treated         1.0815668
## 5         NKCells SP ID treated         1.3859746
## 6     Neutrophils SP ID treated         1.0534358
## 7       StemCells SP ID treated         0.8532976
## 8    StromalCells SP ID treated         0.9427313
## 9        abTcells SP ID treated         1.2800739
## 10       gdTCells SP ID treated         1.0023222
```

Equivalent versions are possible in base and data.table, if you prefer. Or take a direct route:

```
aggregate(cbind(pairwise_division = `mean(score)`) ~ celltype, 
          df[order(df$celltype, df$sample), ], 
          FUN = function(x){x[2]/x[1]})

##          celltype pairwise_division
## 1          Bcells         0.9676300
## 2  DendriticCells         1.1952416
## 3     Macrophages         0.8434003
## 4       Monocytes         1.0815668
## 5         NKCells         1.3859746
## 6     Neutrophils         1.0534358
## 7       StemCells         0.8532976
## 8    StromalCells         0.9427313
## 9        abTcells         1.2800739
## 10       gdTCells         1.0023222
```

Comment: Thanks but how come the value is not `0.967630031` for the first row of your result?

Comment: Oops, divided backwards and posted the wrong version. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

if your data is ordered and fully paired:

```
pair_index <- 1:(dim(df)[1]/2)*2
df[pair_index,'pairwise-division'] <- df[pair_index,3] / df[pair_index-1,3]
df[pair_index,c(1,2,4)]
```